# Can't Watch Videos in Firefox

Tags: firefox, video, webm

This began happening as of recently. Every time I try to watch a video in Firefox, it only plays the first few frames of the video repeatedly throughout the entire time as the audio continues playing normally. This happens only in HTML5 videos. It can play a few videos normally sometimes before this begins happening again, then I have to restart it to fix it once it does. I tried turning off webgl and disabling hardware acceleration with no change. How can I fix Firefox so that I can watch videos on it again?

Comment: Could you test by format on [this](http://techslides.com/sample-webm-ogg-and-mp4-video-files-for-html5) site?

Comment: @Marton Seems to be only HTML5 video, I have edited the question.